# C# turn Datepicker value to Datetime?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datetime, datepicker

How do i turn a Datepicker to Datetime or vice versa

```
void Submit()
            {             

            TimeSpan Days = Date-DateTime.Now;
            CountdownScreen resultpage = new CountdownScreen(Subject.Text, Date.Text);
            NavigationService.Navigate(resultpage);
            }
```

this is the code ive been attempting to work with to get the days from Date (the variable from datepicker) and the current date to get the difference in days

With help of Rufus L the new code looks like

```
TimeSpan duration = Date.SelectedDate.GetValueOrDefault() - DateTime.Now;
//+1 to add the extra day as it seems to round down days 
int days = duration.Days + 1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [`DatePicker`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datepicker.selecteddate?view=netframework-4.8) control has a `.SelectedDate` property that represents the selected `DateTime` value:

```
TimeSpan duration = datePicker.SelectedDate.GetValueOrDefault() - DateTime.Now;
```

Or, to get the difference in days:

```
// TotalDays is a double, since there's a time component, it could be something like 1.25
var days = (datePicker.SelectedDate.GetValueOrDefault() - DateTime.Now).TotalDays;
```

Comment: when i used the .Value it came back with the error"CS1061 'DatePicker' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no accessible extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'DatePicker' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: Ah, it was only `datetimepicker` tagged when I saw the question

Comment: Sorry about that ill change it :)

Comment: Updated the answer. Next time just check the documentation for the class! :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. most the code works except the .TotalDays which comes back an error TimeSpan does not contain a definition for .TotalDays

Comment: But it does... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.totaldays?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Yeah im not sure. i used the first option and used .Days on the timespan to get the right value thank you!